# Meaning of "No cookie for the rookie"

Tags: idioms

From time to time, I listen to people (NBA narrators) saying "no cookie for the rookie", normally when there is a very good play at the game. Does someone know what it can be?

There is an example in this video, at 2:14: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbYlL2ztmEs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cookie is a reward, in this instance praise from the sports announcer.  A rookie in this instance is a first-year player.  Your link takes us to a compilation of basketball plays, and at 2:14 first-year player for the Philadelphia 'Sixers, Jahlil Okafor, fails to stop an opponent from scoring. (He's #8 in white, in case you want to re-watch him fail.)  So no reward for him.